# How much carrot is too much when baking carrot cake?

Tags: baking, cake, carrots, ratio

I am experimenting with increasing the amount of carrot in carrot cake. The original recipe uses 3 cups of carrots to 2 cups of flour; how much more carrot can I add in addition to the 3 cups without turning the cake into a dense carrot bar?

Comment: I think it still depends on how absorbing your flour is

Comment: The main issue is the liquid that the carrots will release into the cake. You can experiment with macerating the shredded carrots to get them to release some liquid before baking, then reduce the amount of liquid in the recipe according to how much juice comes out of the carrots. Mix the shredded carrots with the sugar that normally goes into the cake and let them sit for 10-15 minutes. Add the carrot/sugar syrup mixture that results into the cake with the wet ingredients. This *might* let you get away with adding more carrots to the batter.

Comment: Is it possible you could tell us how much carrot you are adding by weight? The volume of shredded carrots will vary greatly depending on how they are shredded and to what degree they are compacted into a measuring cup.

Answer (score 4):

There is no exact limit, it's a subjective/linguistic question. With every carrot you add, the proportion of people who recognize your result as "cake" will go down and those who recognize it as something else will go up.

That being said, I now checked my preferred books for recipes that do quickbreads and muffins by the volume, and they tend to have a spread between 0.5 and 1.5 cups of add-in per cup of flour, with Ruhlmann's ratio also containing a fritter (not quickbread!) recipe at 2 cups of zucchini to 1 cup of flour. This means that, for typical tastes, your recipe is already on the high side of carrot. If you want to add more than that, do so incrementally, and don't be surprised when others dismiss it as not being a cake any more.

As mentioned in comments, you will be able to have a stronger carrot taste with a better texture if you would replace the whole fresh carrots for something more concentrated, e.g. partially dehydrated carrots, macerated carrots, or you can search for prepared carrot flavoring (some molecular gastronomy shops carry all kinds of flavoring) or also use something that is strongly reminiscent of carrots, such as a small drop of nigella oil.